# Notepad++ does not detect attribute change from read-only to writable

Tags: windows, notepad++, text-editors, version-control, file-attributes

My Notepad++ v8.5.1 does not recognize when **an opened file changes from read-only to writable** (by checking out in ClearCase). It still simply does not edit when typing.

Even Reload / Reload from Disk does not help.
Settings > MISC > File Status Auto-Detection and Notepad++ auto-updater are enabled.
I had to close and newly open the file to be able to edit it.

Is there some other setting I missed? Or may this be a bug?

UltraEdit detects this correctly.
I use Win 10.

---

*Edit: It is possible to uncheck "Read-Only" in the Edit menu or in the context menu of the file. After that editing is possible.

Nevertheless in my opinion it would make more sense, that "Reload" behaves like opening the file newly, and therefore unset the Read-Only mode automatically (or at least ask for doing so).*